# Impossível acessar com o Firefox ver 29.0.1

Tags: bug, status-pronto, login

Não consigo acessar o Stack com o novo build do Firefox. 29.0.1

Quando vou para a tela de login e mando ele fazer o login com o facebook. Ele indentifica meu login e faz um redirect, porém ele vai para uma página sem estar realmente logado, e ai ele me redirecionado denovo para a página de login.
Assim em um círculo sem fim.
Tive que Abrir com o Chrome! :(

Ao clicar em Login pelo Facebook, ele me da um alo Dorathoto(meu usuário) porém ele redireciona denovo para a tela sem login. ai clico em login e mesma coisa. já tentei F5, ctrl+F5, limpar cache..nada..

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A nível de informação, uso o FF 29.0.1 e consigo fazer login usando minha conta da Google.

Comment: Acabo de testar com o FF 29.0.1 no Windows e não pude reproduzir. Tudo normal.

Comment: pelo facebook conta não vai. ele fica em um refresh infinito. ele até identifica.

Comment: Está acontecendo algo similar comigo, mas é com o Chorme e é exclusivo para o Meta Startup. Trocar de browser ou de perfil no Google Chrome funcionam, mas não é a solução que eu queria. Novamente, apenas a nível de informação.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ao fazer a limpeza novamente de todo o cache, dados offline, etc do Firefox 29.0.1
Depois fiz o login no facebook.
Depois cliquei no Login do stackoverflow funcionou perfeitamente. Creio que poderia ser algum cookie corrompido ou algo parecido.

Caso solucionado.

Comment: Aceite a sua resposta